# Getting strange output when printing result of a string comparison

Tags: java, string

I am facing a problem with this line (commented below):

```
System.out.println("Using == ::"+s3==s4)
```

which outputs `false`.

However, `System.out.println(s3==s4)` outputs `true`.

Now, I am not able to understand why I am getting this result:

```
public class string {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s3="Shantanu";
        String s4=s3;
        String s1=new String("java");
        String s2=new String("javaDeveloper");

        System.out.println("Using Equals Method::"+s1.equals(s2));
        System.out.println("Using Equals Method::"+s3.equals(s4));
        System.out.println("Using == ::"+s3==s4);//Problem is here in this line
        System.out.println(s1+"Directly printing the s2 value which is autocasted from superclass to string subclass ");
        System.out.println("Directly printing the s1 value which is autocasted from superclass to string subclass "+s2);
        System.out.println(s3);
    }
}
```

```
Output-Using Equals Method::false
Using Equals Method::true
Using == ::false
java Directly printing the s2 value which is autocasted from superclass to string subclass
Directly printing the s1 value which is autocasted from superclass to string subclass javaDeveloper
```

Comment: @roippi are you a Pointy-haired Boss ? ?

Comment: Your output is not consistent with your code. The third line should just be `false`.

Comment: Please check that your posted output is correct. Obviously the beginning characters "Output-" wouldn't be there. Plus the last `println` call isn't shown printing `s3` and the middle line is suspect.

Comment: @roippi If you hire someone because they know string concatenation has higher precedence than an equality comparison, you deserve what you get. Why not just ask those FaceBook questions, "74% of people can't get this right. What is 7 + 3 x 2 ?"

Comment: Your given output is wrong. See my answer. System.out.println("Using == ::"+s3==s4); --> prints only 'false'

Comment: The text above the code has the right output. The 'output' section below it does not. Some people saw the above part first and some saw the below part first. All the answers saw the real issue and ignored the messy output below.

Comment: @LeeMeador you're right.  I'll steal that question too.  Thanks.

Comment: @roippi ಠ_ಠ Those aren't good questions.

Comment: Rather than using `==` you can use `.equals`. It is much more efficient than `==`. `==` fails when we are checking different types of string values. For e.g. `strObject==strVariable`. It will retun false, even if both string containing same values.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're missing a set of brackets:

```
System.out.println("Using == ::" + (s3==s4));
```

In your version, `"Using == ::" + s3` is being compared via `==` to `s4`, which isn't what you want.

In general, `+` has a higher [precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than `==`, which is why `"Using == ::" + s3==s4` is being evaluated as `("Using == ::" + s3) == s4`.

Comment: So out of curiosity, what was evaluating in his code?  Oh I think I get it, it's comparing the whole string +s3 to s4, which is obviously false.

Comment: `("Using == ::" + s3) == s4`

Comment: Interesting twist on the usual `.equals` questions.  +1

Comment: Then it should print "false" and not "Using = ::false". No?

Comment: @LeeMeador It actually *does* print only false; the OP's output is not consistent with his code.

Comment: How would you know that?

Answer (score 15):

You are using this code:

```
System.out.println("Using == ::"+ s3==s4);
```

Which is being evaluated as:

```
System.out.println( ("Using == ::" + s3) == s4);
```

Hence you are getting **false** as output.

Reason is that as per the operator precedence `+` is higher than `==` as per this `Operator Precedence` table: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

As other answers say you need to use brackets enclosing your boolean expression:

```
System.out.println("Using == ::" + (s3==s4));
```

Comment: This is the best explanation of _why_ the output is what it is, but would be better with an explanation of how to fix it.

Comment: @Michelle: IMO First I need to explain why OP's getting wrong output then my answer would be better understood. Pls check the edit now.

Answer (score 5):

The line is correct:

`"Using == ::"+s3` is not equals to `s4`

You'll need to change your code:

```
"Using == ::"+(s3==s4)
```

**edit:**
The output of the give code is:

```
Using Equals Method::false
Using Equals Method::true
false
javaDirectly printing the s2 value which is autocasted from superclass to string subclass 
Directly printing the s1 value which is autocasted from superclass to string subclass javaDeveloper
Shantanu
```

Comment: So string concatenation has a higher precedence than a a comparison operator? Plus ... why would it print the literal string if it was just comparing it?

Comment: According to this - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html it has.

Comment: Then it should print "false" and not "Using = ::false"

Comment: The output in the question is wrong. I run the proivided code and got the expected output (added to my answer).