# Java : string operators precedence == vs +

Tags: java, string

Can someone please explain to me why this code print only **false** *(Not Both are equal: false)*

```
String one = "length: 10";
String two = "length: " + one.length();
System.out.println("Both are equal:" + one == two);
```

Comment: @Hülya The OP's question is about why the output is `false` and not `Both are equal: false`. Although comparing strings with `==` is typically wrong, this question is more about how string concatenation works.

Comment: @Slaw you're right, I'm removing the comment...

Comment: But still duplicate :) : https://stackoverflow.com/q/18238056/10367471

Comment: @Hülya Good find. Marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the brackets here:

```
System.out.println("Both are equal:" + (one == two));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
System.out.println("Both are equal:" + one == two);
```

is evaluated as

```
System.out.println(("Both are equal:" + one) == two);
```

i.e. first `one` is appended to "Both are equal:" , which results in the `String` "Both are equal:length: 10", and then that `String` is compared to `two`, which results in `false`, so only `false` is printed.

What you want is

```
System.out.println("Both are equal:" + (one == two));
```